# Ejected React app stuck on “Starting the development server” after changing entry config

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I need to support multiple entry points in the React App. One of the option to do that is via eject: `npm run eject`.

Here is an original source I use [How to Add Multiple Entry Points to Your React App](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-add-multiple-entry-points-to-your-react-app-ea8bc015d410)

Create a new application and eject it:

```
$ npx create-react-app react-hello
$ cd react-hello
$ npm run eject
```

Then add into `App.js`:

```
import React from "react";
```

And start application to make sure it works with default configuration:

```
$ npm start
```

To be able to have multiple entry points, I have to adopt the configuration of `entry` in the `config/webpack.config.js`. Original configuration looks like (without comments):

```
entry: [
 isEnvDevelopment &&
    require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
  paths.appIndexJs,
].filter(Boolean),
```

To support multiple entries, I have to convert it into the associative array/hash table, in this case I use `index` as a key for the default index page:

```
entry: {
  index: [
    isEnvDevelopment && require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
    paths.appIndexJs
   ].filter(Boolean)
},
```

And as soon as I change the format, the `npm start` stucks and `Starting the development server...` lasts forever. I try to build it and get an error:

```
$ npm run build

...
> node scripts/build.js

Creating an optimized production build...

Failed to compile.

Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
```

Note: I haven't added a new entry yet, I only modify the current entry to be able to add another one later.

[Webpack Entry Points](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/) says my configuration is correct.

What am I doing wrong and miss, could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue. For me, the problem came from the "ManifestPlugin" further down. It looks like the initial configuration refers to the default "main" entry point key.

```
new ManifestPlugin({
    fileName: 'asset-manifest.json',
    publicPath: paths.publicUrlOrPath,
    generate: (seed, files, entrypoints) => {
      const manifestFiles = files.reduce((manifest, file) => {
        manifest[file.name] = file.path;
        return manifest;
      }, seed);
      
      // This next line is the problem!!!!
      const entrypointFiles = entrypoints.main.filter(
        fileName => !fileName.endsWith('.map')
      );

      return {
        files: manifestFiles,
        entrypoints: entrypointFiles,
      };
    },
  }),
```

Because you made the entry point into "index" instead of "main", entrypoints.main is now undefined. If you were to change the above code to entrypoints.index, then the code should work as expected. However, this solution is not very flexible and only includes one entry point. The final solution I came up with was this.

```
new ManifestPlugin({
    fileName: 'asset-manifest.json',
    publicPath: paths.publicUrlOrPath,
    generate: (seed, files, entrypoints) => {
      const manifestFiles = files.reduce((manifest, file) => {
        manifest[file.name] = file.path;
        return manifest;
      }, seed);
      const entrypointFiles = Object.values(entrypoints).map(values => {
        return values.filter(
          fileName => !fileName.endsWith('.map')
        )
      });

      return {
        files: manifestFiles,
        entrypoints: entrypointFiles,
      };
    },
  }),
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this issue using an ejected create-react-app 5.0.1 as-well.

In addition to the above answer, had to change the webpack output filename from `static/js/bundle.js` `static/js/[name].js`

```
output: {
  filename: isEnvProduction
    ? "static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js"
    : isEnvDevelopment && "static/js/bundle.js
```

to

```
output: {
  filename: isEnvProduction
    ? "static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js"
    : isEnvDevelopment && "static/js/[name].js"
```